# Yii 2.0 Class Pjax not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, pjax

Im using Yii 2.0 basic version, i'm trying to use Pjax but the documentation is very unclarifying, I can't uderstand if this widget is already installed with the basic package or if i should install it.

I've tried using this on my template:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Base_URL; ?>?r=site/pjax">ALO</a>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

But it's not working i get:
Class 'Pjax' not found

I've tried installing it via bower with this guide that i found but i can't understand the server config part and after running the command (bower install...)  it is still not working
https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax

Can someone enlight me?

I really want to use Pjax on my project, to increase it's speed
(it's a very heavy use of data and i need it to run faster by not realoading things that never change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pjax widget is included by default, no need to additionally install it.

Your problem is related with namespaces.

Either specify full namespace in use section:

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
```

and then use it as `Pjax`.

Or specify full namespace with leading back slash like so: `\yii\widgets\Pjax`.

Using first option most of the times is more flexible approach.

If you don't specify anything `Pjax` is considered as located in root namespace and it obviously don't exist there.

Read more about namespaces in [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Here is [Yii 2 official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html) for Pjax widget.

You can see full namespaces of used classes there.

Comment: Oh yeah thats it! I'm so silly, totally forgot to include the widget!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Base_URL; ?>?r=site/pjax">ALO</a>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i forgot to include the class hahaha